# Kotlin language get class at runtime

Tags: reflection, kotlin

Let's say that we have the following:

```
val person = "Bill"
```

Could someone explain the difference between these two:

```
val kClass1 = person.javaClass.kotlin
```

**vs**

```
val kClass2 = person::class
```

When I should call the one instead of the other?

Any source code example would be appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The main reason there are two ways to achieve the same thing, namely get the Kotlin class of an object, is because prior to Kotlin 1.1, the `::class` literal did not support the expression on its left-hand side. So if you're using Kotlin 1.0, your only option is `.javaClass.kotlin`, otherwise you're fine with either of them. This is the reason "Kotlin in Action" uses the `.javaClass.kotlin` syntax: it was written before the Kotlin 1.1 release.

There's also a minor difference in the types of these expressions. For example, in the following code

```
interface T

fun f1(x: T) = x::class
fun f2(x: T) = x.javaClass.kotlin
```

`f1`'s type is `KClass<out T>`, but `f2`'s type is `KClass<T>`. This is actually an oversight in the `javaClass` declaration: `KClass<out T>` is more correct in this case, because `x`'s class is not necessarily `T`, but can also be a subclass of `T`.

Otherwise these two expressions (`x.javaClass.kotlin` and `x::class`) are completely equivalent in terms of produced bytecode and runtime performance. I prefer `x::class` because it's shorter and reads better.

Answer (score 0):

`person.javaClass.kotlin` creates new Kotlin class reference object from Java class. So it makes sense only if you have only java class object.

So you should use `person::class` because in this case you just get Kotlin class directly without additional objects allocation

Comment: In serialization the writer of "Kotlin in Action" prefers the "person.javaClass.kotlin" and not the "person::class". Why does the writer not prefer the "::class"?

Comment: In "Kotlin in Action" I see only one mention of `javaClass.kotlin ` and it's an example how you can get KClass from Class

Comment: I am trying to understand this example: https://try.kotlinlang.org/#/Kotlin%20in%20Action/Chapter%2010/10.2/1_1_ReflectionAPI.kt

Comment: It's just an example. It is paragraph from "Kotlin in Action" about this code fragment:
"You get an instance of KClass by writing MyClass::class. To get the class of an object at runtime, first you obtain its Java class using the javaClass property, which is a direct equivalent to Java’s java.lang.Object.getClass(). Then you access the .kotlin extension property to move from Java to Kotlin reflection API"

Answer (score 0):

No one can replace another one, They both have reason to exist.

**IF** you get a `KClass` from a variable that can't be `null` then you prefer to using `foo::class` since `javaClass.kotlin` create a new instance each time, for example:

```
assert(foo::class === foo::class); 
assert(foo.javaClass.kotlin !== foo.javaClass.kotlin);
```

**IF** you get a `KClass` from a nullable variable then prefer to using as below:

```
val value:Int? = 1;

val type = value?.javaClass?.kotlin;
```

**IF** you get a java `Class` from kotlin you want to transform to `KClass` then using `Class.kotlin` for example:

```
val javaClass:Class<Integer> = ...;
val kotlinClass:KClass<Integer> = javaClass.kotlin;
```

Comment: you're wrong:  

    `.foo.javaClass.kotlin === foo.javaClass.kotlin`

Comment: @Saxintosh that's interesting, it seems to vary. https://pl.kotl.in/cCAS9ewlL prints "false", showing that this answer is correct (and that you're wrong). However, the same file compiled with the same version of Kotlin but running on my local machine prints "true".

Comment: Yep! it varies because of the implementation of .kotlin that rely on `Reflection.getOrCreateKotlinClass()`